# On prefetch radio button does not get checked

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

1. I require `[(ngModel)]="salutation" #salutation="ngModel"` for validation and having this is preventing my radio button to be selected onLoad
2. compareOptions() returns true
3. Using version angular4.1.2

```html
    <app-validation-message [validation-control]="salutation">
          <app-styled-input [title]="'Male'" >
            <div  class="custom-radio" >
              <input id="female" name="salutation" type="radio" [value]="options[0].id"  [checked]="this.compareOptions(options[0]))"
                    [required]="required" [(ngModel)]="salutation" #salutation="ngModel">
              <label for="female"><span></span>{{options[0]['title']}}</label>
            </div>
            <div  class="custom-radio margin-left-10" >
              <input id="male" name="salutation" type="radio" [value]="options[1]"
                     [checked]="this.compareOptions(options[1])"
                    [required]="required" [(ngModel)]="salutation" #salutation="ngModel">
              <label for="female"><span></span>{{options[1]['title']}}</label>
            </div>

          </app-styled-input>
        </app-validation-message>
```

**Component :**

```js
    compareOptions(obj:any){     
         return obj.id===this.personalData.salutation.id;
       }
```

Comment: just as a sidecomment, please avoid calling methods in template, they are fired everytime angular runs change detection, which can be **often**. Use variables in template instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Try add `[attr.checked]="true"` to your radio button, it work perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you iterate your `options` instead of writing the template long hand. And as I mentioned in comment, avoid calling methods in template, they will be executed each time Angular runs change detection, which can be quite often. So what we want to do, is to set the initial value to your `ngModel`, i.e `salutation`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.salutation = this.personalData.salutation.id;
}
```

now we can also get rid of the `[checked]` attribute in the template, as we are using the `ngModel` instead. So you modify your template to the following:

```html
<div *ngFor="let opt of options">{{opt.title}}
  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="salutation" name="option" 
         #option="ngModel" [value]="opt.id" />
</div>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1vAlRdhVSMPH12VEg5Fj?p=preview

Comment: Hi. salutation here is an object with id and title, if i make model this.personalData.id, my validation fails, for validation ,am passing my model [validation-control]="salutation"

Comment: Well as it sits in your code, salutation is already pointing to just the id. I'm unsure of what you actually want here now. Could you please fork the plunker with showing exactly what the issue is?